# What's the right way to validate JSON data coming from an AJAX POST request?

Tags: rest-api, json, validation, parameter, endpoints

I'm building a little plugin with a send button: when clicked, the button calls (from the admin area) a rest api endpoint, passing JSON data through AJAX. Everything works very well and the callback correctly receives the JSON data.

Now, I want to validate the data using the `validate_callback` [function](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/).

Problem is I only could find examples where they validate an API parameter, and I have no parameter in my API.

A typical example:

```
 register_rest_route( 'route/v1', '/endpoint/', array(
'methods' => 'POST',
'callback' => array( $this, 'endpoint_post_handler' ),
'permissions_callback' => 'is_user_logged_in',
'args' => array(
    'first_name' => array(
        'required' => true,
        'type' => 'string',
        'description' => 'The client\'s first name',
    ),
)
```

) );

Here the developer is validating the first_name parameter, for example.

This is another example, from the official docs:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'myplugin/v1', '/author/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
    'args' => array(
      'id' => array(
        'validate_callback' => function($param, $request, $key) {
          return is_numeric( $param );
        }
      ),
    ),
  ) );
} );
```

What if I have no parameter at all but I still want to validate the request content?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you mean you want to validate the JSON is formed correctly, that's probably not your job. The libraries on each side are responsible for correctly forming the JSON, and you just have to deal with the data inside.

Comment: @mozboz It's not the JSON correctness, but its content: I want to verify the content is what the application is supposed to receive